# Como faço para diminuir meu código? (Estudos) Calculadora PHP

Tags: php, matemática

Fiz uma calculadora PHP, com require peguei a função de outra aba etc... Eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer para exemplificar minha function, exemplo fazer uma calculadora em so uma fuction não usar varias e cada uma com uma operação, se puderem me instruir, agradeço.

**meu código principal:**

require 'function.php';

```
$soma = somar(10,5);
$diferenca = subtrair(10, 5);
$produto = multiplicar(10, 5);
$quociente = dividir(10, 5);

echo 'A soma de 10 e 5 é: ' . $soma . "\n";
echo 'A diferença entre 10 e 5 é: ' . $diferenca . "\n";
echo 'O produto de 10 por 5 é: ' . $produto ."\n";
echo 'O quociente de 10 por 5 é: ' . $quociente;
```

**function que usei:**

```
function somar($a ,$b){
   return $a + $b;
}
function subtrair($a,$b){
   return $a - $b;
}
function multiplicar($a ,$b){
   return $a * $b;
}
function dividir($a ,$b){
   return $a / $b;
}
```

Comment: Dá pra fazer sim em uma function - basta receber a operação como parâmetro (em um enum, ou uma constante que identifique o tipo, por exemplo). Mas, o código **não ficaria melhor**. Normalmente, não é uma boa opção juntar tudo em uma function - isso aumenta a complexidade de leitura (entre outros possíveis problemas).

Comment: O que deu pra entender dessa pergunta, algo parecido com isso:
echo 'A soma de 10 e 5 é: ' . ($a + $b) . "\n";
echo 'A diferença entre 10 e 5 é: ' . ($a - $b) . "\n";
echo 'O produto de 10 por 5 é: ' . ($a * $b) ."\n";
echo 'O quociente de 10 por 5 é: ' . ($a / $b);

Comment: @Froslass é somente para ser um exemplo do que vai exibir o importante e a calculadora, por que a única coisa que quero é  saber se tem como diminuir a função.

Comment: Então o que eu escrevi acima serve

Answer (score 0):

Como levei em consideração que você está iniciando, fiz algo bem simples e bem "porco". Mas o intuito aqui é você poder analisar o código, e ver de uma outra forma. **NÃO** recomendo utilizar essa forma que fiz, embora você pode otimizar o código ou com base nele criar outro "melhor" (*Não existe sempre um código **melhor** se funcionou e atendeu a demanda então está ok, se preocupe com performance e detalhes mais avançados, quando estiver mais acostumado a programar)*

**O código ficou assim:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', true);

$numero1 = !empty($_POST['numero1']) ? intval($_POST['numero1']) : 0;
$numero2 = !empty($_POST['numero2']) ? intval($_POST['numero2']) : 0;
$operadores = $_POST['operadores'] ?? null;

function calcular($numero1, $numero2, $operador)
{
    switch ($operador) {
        case 'somar':
            return $numero1 + $numero2;
            break;
        case 'subtrair':
            return $numero1 - $numero2;
            break;
        case 'dividir':
            if ($numero1 === 0 || $numero2 === 0) {
                echo '<a href="">Voltar</a>';
                throw new DivisionByZeroError('Divisão por zero');
            }
            return $numero1 / $numero2;
            break;
        case 'multiplicar':
            return $numero1 * $numero2;
            break;
    }
}

$resultado = calcular($numero1, $numero2, $operadores);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="numero1">Campo1: </label>
        <input id="numero1" name="numero1" type="text" style="margin-right: 5px; font-size: 1.4rem;">
        <select name="operadores" id="operadores" style="width: 50px !important; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 1.4rem;">
            <option value="somar" <?=$operadores === 'somar' ? 'selected' : '';?>>+</option>
            <option value="subtrair" <?=$operadores === 'subtrair' ? 'selected' : '';?>>-</option>
            <option value="dividir" <?=$operadores === 'dividir' ? 'selected' : '';?>>/</option>
            <option value="multiplicar" <?=$operadores === 'multiplicar' ? 'selected' : '';?>>*</option>
        </select>
        <label for="numero2">Campo2: </label>
        <input id="numero2" name="numero2" type="text" style="margin-right: 5px; font-size: 1.4rem;">
        <button style="font-size: 1.4rem;">Calcular</button><br>
        <label for="resultado">Resultado: </label>
        <input id="resultado" name="resultado" type="text" readonly value="<?= $resultado; ?>" style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Eu fiz de propósito** de uma forma que fique faltando validações, e utilizei algumas variáveis e escopo que não são tão recomendáveis para programar, mas a **ideia** é fazer você **analisar**, **entender**, e criar um **novo** à partir de seu entendimento.

Answer (score -2):

Visualizando o seu problema eu reparo que, você já fez um código curto o suficiente para a proposta, mas ainda sim tem como melhorar mais utilizando as [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arrow.php) do PHP, você pode consultar a documentação para mais exemplos, resolução abaixo:

```html
<?php

//Como está:
function somar($a ,$b){
   return $a + $b;
}

//Como vai ficar:
$somar = fn($a) => fn($b) => $a + $b;

//Uso:
$resultado = $somar(2, 5);

?>
```